# How to override PrestShop 1.7.7 module classes?

Tags: module, overriding, prestashop-1.7

I want to override class `MySQL` of PrestaShop module `ps_facetedsearch` that is located in file: `mystore/modules/ps_facetedsearch/src/Adapter/MySQL.php`

How do I achieve this?

---

EDIT:

Class `MySQL` that I want to override is defined in file `mystore/modules/ps_facetedsearch/src/Adapter/MySQL.php`.
This class is used by class `Search` of same module and is defined in file `mystore/modules/ps_facetedsearch/src/Product/Search.php`. Class `Search` is used by another module class and so on, so there is a long 'chain' of classes.

Do I need to extend all chained classes or can I somehow override only the `MySQL` class that really requires modification?

Answer (score 1):

**Override Module Classes**

To modify behavior of a module’s class you have to put your modified class at

```
ROOT/override/modules/MODULENAME/OVERRIDECLASS.php
```

You have to create a PHP file on the location below and call it **ps_facetedsearch.php**

```
ROOT/override/modules/ps_facetedsearch/ps_facetedsearch.php
```

Inside the overriding class you can add the code below.

```
<?php
    class Ps_FacetedsearchOverride extends Ps_Facetedsearch
    {
        public function getContent()
        {
            return "Hello store owner! this code is brought to you by crezzur.com";
        }
    }
?>
```

After saving your ps_facetedsearch.php override and clearing the Prestashop cache you will see the message "**Hello store owner! this code is brought to you by crezzur.com**" when you open the module ps_facetedsearch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I was asking about a class that module uses, not the module class itself. Please see my edit.